# Grouping, dynamic key formation, pivitoing information in C# & generating json output

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq

I am getting some hierarchical data in flat format from SQL server. This is how the data looks.

```
Group       Name        Level   Parent       Value1      Value2   RowID
Global      Product1     1                     10            20     1
APAC        Product1     1                     80            90     2
EMEA        Product1     1                     50            70     3
Global      Product2     2      Product1       100          200     4
APAC        Product2     2      Product1       800          900     5
EMEA        Product2     2      Product1       500          700     6
Global      Product3     3      Product2       10            20     7
APAC        Product3     3      Product2       80            90     8
Global      Product4     4      Product3       110           120     9
APAC        Product4     4      Product3       810           190     10
EMEA        Product4     4      Product3       510           170     11
.....
.....   
Global      Product12     1                     10            20     100
```

I need to group the data based on `Name and Level` columns. Then I need to create multiple keys based on combination of `Group Column & Value1 & Value2 columns`. See the below `JSON` output to get more idea about the output. Please keep in mind number of Group can change.

```
[
   {
     Id: 1,
     Name: Product1,
     parentId: null,
     GlobalValue1: 10,
     GlobalValue2: 20,
     APACValue1: 80,
     APACValue2: 90,
     EMEAValue1: 50,
     EMEAValue2: 70
   },
  {
     Id: 2,
     Name: Product2,
     parentId: 1, 
     GlobalValue1: 100,
     GlobalValue2: 200,
     APACValue1: 800,
     APACValue2: 900,
     EMEAValue1: 500,
     EMEAValue2: 700
   },
   {
     Id: 3,
     Name: Product3,
     parentId: 2, 
     GlobalValue1: 10,
     GlobalValue2: 20,
     APACValue1: 80,
     APACValue2: 90,
     EMEAValue1: null,
     EMEAValue2: null
   },
   {
     Id: 4,
     Name: Product4,
     parentId: 3, 
     GlobalValue1: 110,
     GlobalValue2: 120,
     APACValue1: 810,
     APACValue2: 190,
     EMEAValue1: 510,
     EMEAValue2: 170
   }{
     Id: 122,
     Name: Product12,
     parentId: null3, 
     GlobalValue1: 10,
     GlobalValue2: 20,
     APACValue1: null,
     APACValue2: null,
     EMEAValue1: null,
     EMEAValue2: null
   }



]
```

I need to auto generate ID field. This field will be use to establish parent-child relationship. `I cannot rely on`name`column as it can repeat (can have same value) across different levels.`. There will be more than 1 product and each level. In my example, I am just showing one product per level just to keep example simple.

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a dictionary from your table and then serialize that. See for example, [this](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializedictionary.htm).

Comment: @MattBurland: thank you for quick reply. Please correct me if I am wrong. But this is just a cog in the wheel. It tells me how to serialize the data. But before I do that I need to figure out how to generate keys and manage parent child relationship. How do I group the data? How do I manage null values. I have certain ideas but there are too many moving pieces & I am little confused.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear on how the relationships are supposed to work, but *I think* you are looking to group by `Level` (it looks like `Level` and `Name` are basically 1-to-1), then for each item in each group, create a dictionary and concatenate `Group` and the column names (`Value1`, `Value2`) to make dictionary keys and stick the relevant values in. Then stick the dictionary in a array and serialize the whole thing. It's not clear where your `Id` in the output comes from. Is that just `Level`?

Comment: Just create an array (linq would be the best way) from your input and then serialize it.

Comment: @MattBurland: I am not sure what you meant by `level and name are basically 1to1`. I am tying to group data by name and level columns. Since the name field can be duplicate across levels, I cannot rely on it to showcase parent child relationship & that is what I want to create ID field.

Comment: So what is `Level`? Can there be more than one product in a `Level`? That's what I mean, it appears that there is only 1 level per product. But either way, it doesn't change the basic premise. You group it (you could use `GroupBy`) to group it however you want to group it and then you iterate through the groups and in each group iterate through the rows of data and build up keys and stick them in a dictionary.

Comment: @MattBurland: Yes, each level will have more than 1 product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a bit of code that does what I think you want. It's a console application and I used Newtonsoft.Json (get it with NuGet in references) to create the JSON.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = initData();
        var result = getGroupedData(data);
        var json = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer
        {
            Formatting=Formatting.Indented
        };
        json.Serialize(Console.Out,result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static object getGroupedData(DataTable dt)
    {
        var id = 1;
        var rows = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>(); //because for some reason DataRowCollection is not an IEnumerable<DataRow>
        var products = rows //the products, each defined by Name and Level
          .GroupBy(r => new { Name = r.Field<string>("Name"), Level = r.Field<int>("Level") })
          .Select(g => new
          {
              Id = id++, //create the id
              Name = g.Key.Name,
              Level = g.Key.Level,
              // select the parent and throw exception if there are more or less than one
              Parent = g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("Parent")).Distinct().Single() 
          }).ToList();
        var results = products
          .Select(p => new //need a partial result first, containing the Global, Apac and Emea rows, if they exist
          {
              Id = p.Id,
              Name = p.Name,
              // Assuming the Level of a child is Level of parent+1
              Parent = products.FirstOrDefault(par => par.Name == p.Parent && par.Level + 1 == p.Level),
              Global = rows.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("Name") == p.Name && r.Field<int>("Level") == p.Level && r.Field<string>("Group") == "Global"),
              Apac = rows.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("Name") == p.Name && r.Field<int>("Level") == p.Level && r.Field<string>("Group") == "APAC"),
              Emea = rows.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("Name") == p.Name && r.Field<int>("Level") == p.Level && r.Field<string>("Group") == "EMEA")
          })
          .Select(x => new //create the final result
          {
              Id = x.Id,
              Name = x.Name,
              ParentId = x.Parent==null? (int?)null :x.Parent.Id,
              GlobalValue1 = x.Global == null ? (double?)null : x.Global.Field<double?>("Value1"),
              GlobalValue2 = x.Global == null ? (double?)null : x.Global.Field<double?>("Value2"),
              APACValue1 = x.Apac == null ? (double?)null : x.Apac.Field<double?>("Value1"),
              APACValue2 = x.Apac == null ? (double?)null : x.Apac.Field<double?>("Value2"),
              EMEAValue1 = x.Emea == null ? (double?)null : x.Emea.Field<double?>("Value1"),
              EMEAValue2 = x.Emea == null ? (double?)null : x.Emea.Field<double?>("Value2")
          })
          .ToArray();
        return results;
    }

    private static DataTable initData()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Group", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Level", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Parent", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Value1", typeof(double));
        dt.Columns.Add("Value2", typeof(double));
        dt.Columns.Add("RowID", typeof(int));
        dt.Rows.Add("Global", "Product1", 1, null, 10, 20, 1);
        dt.Rows.Add("APAC", "Product1", 1, null, 80, 90, 2);
        dt.Rows.Add("EMEA", "Product1", 1, null, 50, 70, 3);
        dt.Rows.Add("Global", "Product2", 2, "Product1", 100, 200, 1);
        dt.Rows.Add("APAC", "Product2", 2, "Product1", 800, 900, 2);
        dt.Rows.Add("EMEA", "Product2", 2, "Product1", 500, 700, 3);
        dt.Rows.Add("Global", "Product3", 3, "Product2", 10, 20, 1);
        dt.Rows.Add("APAC", "Product3", 3, "Product2", 80, 90, 2);
        dt.Rows.Add("Global", "Product4", 4, "Product3", 110, 120, 1);
        dt.Rows.Add("APAC", "Product4", 4, "Product3", 810, 190, 2);
        dt.Rows.Add("EMEA", "Product4", 4, "Product3", 510, 170, 3);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

With POCO object, the method would look like this:

```
private static object getGroupedData(IEnumerable<MyPoco> rows)
{
    var id = 1;
    var products = rows //the products, each defined by Name and Level
      .GroupBy(r => new { Name = r.Name, Level = r.Level })
      .Select(g => new
      {
          Id = id++, //create the id
          Name = g.Key.Name,
          Level = g.Key.Level,
          // select the parent and throw exception if there are more or less than one
          Parent = g.Select(r => r.Parent).Distinct().Single() 
      }).ToList();
    var results = products
      .Select(p => new //need a partial result first, containing the Global, Apac and Emea rows, if they exist
      {
          Id = p.Id,
          Name = p.Name,
          // Assuming the Level of a child is Level of parent+1
          Parent = products.FirstOrDefault(par => par.Name == p.Parent && par.Level + 1 == p.Level),
          Global = rows.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == p.Name && r.Level == p.Level && r.Group == "Global"),
          Apac = rows.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == p.Name && r.Level == p.Level && r.Group == "APAC"),
          Emea = rows.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == p.Name && r.Level == p.Level && r.Group == "EMEA")
      })
      .Select(x => new //create the final result
      {
          Id = x.Id,
          Name = x.Name,
          ParentId = x.Parent==null? (int?)null :x.Parent.Id,
          GlobalValue1 = x.Global == null ? (double?)null : x.Global.Value1,
          GlobalValue2 = x.Global == null ? (double?)null : x.Global.Value2,
          APACValue1 = x.Apac == null ? (double?)null : x.Apac.Value1,
          APACValue2 = x.Apac == null ? (double?)null : x.Apac.Value2,
          EMEAValue1 = x.Emea == null ? (double?)null : x.Emea.Value1,
          EMEAValue2 = x.Emea == null ? (double?)null : x.Emea.Value2
      })
      .ToArray();
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Updated it for your request to have Name+Level unicity, not just Name

Comment: Thank you for quick reply and multiple edits. I assume in this case `dt` is a datatable. what this line doing `ParentId=products.FirstOrDefault(par=>par.Name==p.Parent&&par.Level+1==p.Level)?.Id,
`. I am unable to compile this code. Can you please explain what you are doing and I will make code compliable.

Comment: It would be much easier if the starting data would not be a DataTable. As you didn't specify it, I assumed 'flat SQL data' means either a DataTable or a DataReader. Let me make a short project and give you the compilable commented correct code.

Comment: Code updated with console app that returns the result you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! I really appreciate it. I can use a normal C# class to store data instead of using data table. Also I am unable to compile the code you have shared (because of C# 6.0 feature.. not sure whats the issue). Can you please share one more sample using a C# class as data source and avoid using C# 6 features. I cant thank you enough !!

Comment: The only C# 6 feature is the Null-Conditional Operator (obj?.something) which is the same as obj==null?default(T):something (where something is of type T). I've updated the code for C# 5.

Comment: Thank you for quick help. Can you please add one more example using POCO & not datatable. Since you said without DataTable It would be lot easier to get the desired results.